# What is the range of the Knock ritual?

Tags: dnd-4e, rituals

The Knock<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/ritual.aspx?id=22)</sup> ritual does not specify anything for range.

Can you use the ritual to unlock a door that you cannot touch?

Can you use the ritual to unlock a door that you cannot see?

Can you use the ritual to unlock a door that is visible at the end of a hallway without approaching it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When ever I encounter a spell or power that doesn't have a range specified I always rule it as a touch or adjacent square which ever makes more sense.  Knock implies touch so, that is what I rule.  As long as the character can touch they can use the power, they don't have to see it.

Answer (score 4):

The `Knock` ritual gives special details on using it to "undo bolts and bars you couldn't normally reach" with a DC 20 Arcana check. That suggests that the ability to "normally reach" the affected locks is part of the spell's typical use.